# Running an asynchronous function inside another with async/await fails to connect/fetch resource

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm building a web application using Node and Express. I have an HTML page which is making requests to my API using the Fetch API. In my table, I have an `X` button for each row, that deletes that task (it's working fine.) However, the deletion function `deleteTask` then calls my `tableTasks` function to reload the table with the new data. The request fails, with the error messages:

> Failed to load resource: Could not connect to server
>   Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Could not connect to the server.

With a link to the correct API endpoint which, when opened from a different source (browser, Postman, different button on form page) yields the results correctly.

I have already tried relocating the `await` keyword to `await tableTasks` from inside `deleteTask`, and used `return`. Now, my code runs inside `tableTasks`, and it stops on this line:

```
const response = await fetch("http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:3000/list");
```

With the above errors. I have tried changing the `await` to `.then` syntax and placing the remainder of `tableTasks` inside a callback function, but to no avail.

In `deleteTask`:

```
tableTasks(false);
```

In `tableTasks`:

```
async function tableTasks() {
    //Initialization
    const response = await fetch("http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:3000/list");
    const data = response.json();
    //Do stuff with data
}
```

My expectation is that when this function is called, it reloads the table, but it errors out. Do I need to place an extra `await` somewhere, or wait on the response in a different manner?

Comment: Encapsulate the code inside your async function in a try/catch block

Comment: @AmitDas It's already throwing the error, why would I need a try/catch?

Comment: the `fetch` command returns a `promise`. A promise has 2 parts. `Resolve` and `Reject`. The `await` keyword returns whatever is returned from the `resolve` part. If there is an error in the `fetch` the `reject` will execute. You need to handle that also else you will get the above error. Also seems there is some server connection error.

Comment: Is that the exact error message? It's non-standard, I can only find a [couple](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22TypeError%3A+Could+not+connect+to+the+server.%22) results, I'm surprised the built-in `fetch` would reject with that message. Wild guess, the HTML page isn't on HTTPS, right? (if it happens to be on HTTPS, that's probably the problem). Another random idea, maybe see what happens when you use `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: No, the server does not run over HTTPS.

Comment: Sure, will do. So adding the try/catch block solved it right?

Comment: @AmitDas No, very sorry - just tested it again, and it still doesn't re-table - the error is caught and logged to the console, but the table still does not reload.

Comment: Ohh ok. So what does the error log say? Also since the promise is rejected, my guess is there is some issue with the server. Do a normal request using POSTMAN or some other client. See what the response is there.

Comment: @AmitDas First an error `GET http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:3000/list net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, then the log `TypeError: failed to fetch`.

Comment: @Jack,just what I suspected. 2 possibilities. Either you are running behind some kind of proxy or firewall which might be refusing to connect to server, or there is some server issue. Send the same request using some other client like POSTMAN or an online rest client. Tell me is it your own server or some other third party?

Comment: Third-party (Amazon), but the API `/list` works perfectly outside of this form - this is the only place it's not working.

Comment: Must be some connection issue on your side.

Answer (score -1):

Always encapsulate your `async` function in a `try/catch` block like so:

```
async function f() {
    try{
          await asynchronous_method();
    }catch(err){
           //Handle Rejection.
    }
}
```

the `fetch` command returns a `promise`. A promise has 2 parts. `Resolve` and `Reject`. The `await` keyword returns whatever is returned from the `resolve` part. If there is an error in the `fetch` the `reject` will execute. You need to handle that also else you will get the above error. Also seems there is some server connection error.